# After install cPanel, normal user account can't use 'su -' to login in as root. What to do?

Tags: ssh

I hardened the SSH by disallow direct root access. To access root, I need to login with normal user account first then use command "su -" to login as root.

However, after install cPanel, when I sent 'su -' command with normal user, it gives me "-bash: /bin/su: Permission denied"

It seems cPanel made some changes of permission to normal user. **Now I can't find a way to login as root**.

What can I do?

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the user to the wheel group in whm and it should give you su privileges again, alternatively use sudo as well but this probably also needs the user adding to the wheel group

Comment: Wow! There is a unicorn that loves your answer very much!